# javascript filter app not working all uls not being processed

Tags: javascript

this is a simple javascript filterable list but for some reason, the outer for loop is running only once **but when I remove inner loop the outer loop runs fine**
the filter is only running on first ul the other uls are being ignored
can someone correct the code

```
  <div style="margin-left:40%; width:20%">
 <h1>SEARCH</h1>
<input type="text" class="search">
<ul class="collection">
  <li class="collection-item"><h2>A</h2></li>
  <li class="collection-item">Adam</li>

  <li class="collection-item">Alan</li>
  <li class="collection-item">aspen</li>
  <li class="collection-item">Andrew</li>

</ul>
<ul class="collection">
  <li class="collection-item"><h2>B</h2></li>
  <li class="collection-item">Bob</li>

  <li class="collection-item">Builder</li>
  <li class="collection-item">Brown</li>
  <li class="collection-item">Brad</li>

</ul>

</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
var search = document.querySelector(".search");
var lists = document.querySelectorAll("ul");
var all_lis = document.querySelectorAll("li");
search.addEventListener('keyup', filter);

function filter(event) {
    console.log("filtering....");
    for (var i = 0; i < all_lis.length; i++) {
        all_lis[i].style.display = "";
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
        var ls = lists[i].querySelectorAll("li");
        console.log(ls);
        for (var i = 1; i < ls.length; i++) {
            if (ls[i].textContent.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value)) {
                ls[i].style.display = "";
                console.log(ls[i]);
            } else {
                ls[i].style.display = "none";
                console.log(ls[i]);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is working fine when i replace inner for loop with forEach but i want to know why  the outer for loop didn't loop when i was using another for loop inside it